# How can I make my Python program communicate with an .exe file to run a specific command line upon startup?

Tags: python, subprocess, chess

I am working on a project whereby I have to link Leela Chess Zero to the backend. However, I do not know how to do so.

The following is my file, where lc0.exe is the exe file for Leela Chess Zero. What I am trying to do is to make the code automatically run the command line `go nodes 1000` when the program starts running. However, when I run the program, lc0.exe will run inside my vscode terminal but it does not run the command line `go nodes 1000`. May I know how I can achieve this?

```
import subprocess

def run_exe():
    p = subprocess.Popen("C:/Users/newli/leela/lc0.exe", shell=True)
    print(p.communicate("go nodes 1000"))

run_exe()
```

I have searched up countless websites and tutorials on subprocess but I have never been able to find an answer, and I would really appreciate it if someone could answer my query. :D

Comment: Did you try adding a CRLF at the end of the communicated command line?

Comment: @Jib yes I did but it still didnt work

Comment: @MarkSetchell i did but it also didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You may rather want to write to the standard input of the process like this:

```
import subprocess

def run_exe():
    p = subprocess.Popen(["C:/Users/newli/leela/lc0.exe"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    print(p.communicate(input="go nodes 1000\n"))

run_exe()
```

Comment: Thank you this almost worked, however the command isnt really ran and this is the output:
('', None)

Comment: It still gives the same error of TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: I tested again using your updated code but it now prints ('', None) again.

Comment: What are you expecting to be output?

Comment: I was expecting it to start running the analysis on the starting position in chess, i.e. info depth 1 seldepth 2 time 411 nodes 2 score cp 15 nps 153 tbhits 0 pv e2e4 e7e5 and more